# Unknown file. How was it created?

Tags: files, home

Suddenly a file (with a space as its name) appeared in my home folder with the following content.

```
ARGC: 1
ARGIND: 0
ARGV: array, 1 elements
BINMODE: 0
CONVFMT: "%.6g"
ENVIRON: array, 65 elements
ERRNO: ""
FIELDWIDTHS: ""
FILENAME: "-"
FNR: 19
FPAT: "[^[:space:]]+"
FS: " "
FUNCTAB: array, 41 elements
IGNORECASE: 0
LINT: 0
NF: 7
NR: 19
OFMT: "%.6g"
OFS: " "
ORS: "\n"
PREC: 53
PROCINFO: array, 28 elements
RLENGTH: 0
ROUNDMODE: "N"
RS: "\n"
RSTART: 0
RT: "\n"
SUBSEP: "\034"
SYMTAB: array, 28 elements
TEXTDOMAIN: "messages"
```

I have no clue how was it created or what it even does, I didn't do anything different than usual. So does anyone know what it is?

Comment: A file can't have no name. It might be a space, or some other non-printable punctuation, but it can't be nothing

Comment: Maybe it's not required for someone smarter than me to answer the question, but I think knowing the OS and filesystem type would be useful in this situation.

Comment: I can't help too much, but it looks to be `awk` related. What's the file name, a space? How did you print the file?

Comment: Looks a bit like an `awk` environ dump

Comment: Sorry, yes, it's a space (I'll change that). But I didn't work with awk anytime recently, and the file creation date is very recent.

Comment: Someone ran GNU `awk` with `-d ' '` as an option, possibly mistyping `cut -d ' '` or similar?

Comment: @Kusalananda thank you! I was trying to find how to get awk to print the values of its internal vars like this. But on my system, `awk -d ' ' ` creates the file `awkvars.out` with this content. It might be version-dependent.

Comment: Thank you @Kusalananda, but as terdon said, it creates a file named "awkvars.out" and not a file with a space

Comment: @terdon Ah, `-d' '` then (no space after option), and with some additional argument for the actual `awk` code, e.g. `awk -d' ' 1 </dev/null`.  In any case, I think it may be a mistyping. The OP should check their command line history. It could also be from some non-portable shell script expecting to be using some other implementation of `awk`.

Comment: @Kusalananda no, I didn't use the `-d` flag anytime recently, only `-F` flag. My command history limit is set to 2000.